# XPages percent field

Tags: xpages

I have the following field on a custom control

```
<xp:inputText id="InterRate" type="number"
    value="#{document1.InterRate}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertNumber type="percent"></xp:convertNumber>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

This displays correctly in read mode, but when switched to edit mode the field loses it's value. Anyone seen the same?

Answer (score 0):

Removing type="number" resolved this.